Shell find exact filename (literal)
How to find file by name without expressions/regex, just exact given name/part of name?
I use it with variable so there could be special characters which will brake search.
I use scratch but dont like it, need clear find/ls
find | grep -F "$name"
Using GNU find
Example that not works
name="Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark -  v1.7 [Proper]"
find -name "$name"


what about find . -name "$name"? if this doesn't 'work' then please update the question with an example of where it doesn't work in your environment

If you're on BSD (or macOS) find -f "$name" might work for you

find's -name predicate interprets its argument as a glob(-ish) pattern. This is interpreted by find, not by the shell, so quoting it to avoid interpretation by the shell is not necessarily sufficient.
In your particular case, find will interpret the [Proper] part of your wanted filename as a character class instead of a literal.  You can obtain suitable quoting of the filename by passing it through printf %q, and quoting the result to avoid the shell dequoting it:
find -name "$(printf %q "$name")"


I knew the reason but needed a solution; this works. Will keep in mind this escape thick with %q. Thanks

Setup:
$ mkdir testd
$ touch testd/"Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark - v1.7 [Proper]"

A simple find does not work since the brackets are treated as special characters:
$ find . -name "$name"
                         -- no output

To insure the brackets are processed as literal strings I'd opt to use the bash builtin printf to escape all special characters:
$ printf "%q" "Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark - v1.7 [Proper]"
Poweramp\ v3\ Skin\ Liv\ Dark\ -\ v1.7\ \[Proper\]

For OP's purpose we will redo the name=... assignment:
#######
# requires a subshell

name=$( printf "%q" "Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark - v1.7 [Proper]" )

#######
# no subshell required

printf -v name "%q" "Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark - v1.7 [Proper]"

Now a simple find should suffice:
$ find . -name "$name"
./testd/Poweramp v3 Skin Liv Dark - v1.7 [Proper]


Thanks for good explanation. I like more short one liner with substitute that suggested John
